# Avoid imaginary result FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I have a code where I'm using `FindRoot` for the equation `toroottp`. I plug in some sample values on `zs,zQ,sig,zh` and plot `toroot` to get a feeling of its range.

I have tried using `tp[9,9.30685,-15.50169,10]` but it produces some errors. I know the error occurs because clearly near `zs=1.1` the plot diverges (the plot is symmetric so there are two roots, one in the positive the other in the negative but choosing the positive wil suffice). The range I put for `FindRoot` say, `{tp, 1, 0.8, 1.15}` produces an error, but if I reduce the upper limit a little bit, say, `{tp, 1, 0.8, 1.12}` then it produces no error.

The question is how do I set up `FindRoot` so that it will not produce an error even if my proposed range goes beyond those that converge. I want to resolve this since I will change my parameters later and use this for other commands, this is a problem since I do not know beforehand where exactly is the root and where it starts to diverge as in the plot. You cannot expect me to check one point at a time just to make sure there is no error, that will be adsurd, but I guess any improvement on my setup will still be beneficial. The major problem here is the upper limit. On the other hand, I think no matter how I change the parameters the plots will have the same form so resolving the upper limit issue wil suffice I guess. Any guidance?

Just a note, I will vary `zs` say in the range `[7,9.9]`. The rest are fixed.

```
d = 3;
ag = 10;
pg = 10;
wp = 40;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);
toroottp[tp_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, sig_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := Module[{tpr, zsr, zQr, sigr, zhr}, {tpr, zsr, zQr, sigr, zhr} = Rationalize[{tp, zs, zQ, sig, zh}, 0]; NIntegrate[SetPrecision[(1/z^d) (Sqrt[1/(f[z, zhr] (1 + (((f[zsr, zhr]^2 tpr^2)/f[z, zhr]) - 1) (z/zsr)^(2 d) (1/(1 - f[zsr, zhr] tpr^2))))] - (Sqrt[zQr^(2 d)/(f[z, zhr] (zQr^(2 d) - z^(2 d) (1 + sigr^2 f[zQr, zhr]^-1)^-1))])), wp], {z, 0, zsr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 300] - NIntegrate[SetPrecision[(1/z^d) (Sqrt[zQr^(2 d)/(f[z, zhr] (zQr^(2 d) - z^(2 d) (1 + sigr^2 f[zQr, zhr]^-1)^-1))]), wp], {z, zsr, zQr}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 300] - 1/zQr^(d - 1)]
tp[zs_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, sig_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := tp /. FindRoot[SetPrecision[toroottp[tp, zs, zQ, sig, zh] == 0, wp], {tp, 1, 0.8, 1.15}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 200]

Plot[toroottp[tp, 9, 9.30685, -15.50169, 10], {tp, -1.2, 1.2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large]

tp[9,9.30685,-15.50169,10]
(*During evaluation of In[1315]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
During evaluation of In[1315]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
During evaluation of In[1315]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
During evaluation of In[1315]:= General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::slwcon will be suppressed during this calculation.
1.111809133761684722509615030076769149700*)
```

[image]

Comment: @MichaelE2 It is not necessary for the FindRoot problem per se but since I'm going to use it for other functions later it should produce some value without error and that is why I placed it there, but I get it.

Comment: I assumed six lines at the bottom of the code was output. I see now that the `tp[...]` is input -- my mistake. One way to set off output is to put it in comments `(* <output> *)`; that has the added benefit that if it's pasted into Mathematica along with the input, it does not affect how the input runs.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Just edited the output in my post, thanks for this reminder.

Comment: The imaginary number problem seems to come from `NIntegrate` (not `FindRoot`). Adding the singularities of the integration to the `Exclusions` seems to fix the problem, but at a severe cost of time (adds 5 to 25 sec. per integration!!): `Exclusions -> Cases[FunctionSingularities[(1/z^d) (Sqrt[1/(f[z, zhr] (1 + (((f[zsr, zhr]^2 tpr^2)/f[z, zhr]) - 1) (z/zsr)^(2 d) (1/(1 - f[zsr, zhr] tpr^2))))] - (Sqrt[zQr^(2 d)/(f[z, zhr] (zQr^(2 d) - z^(2 d) (1 + sigr^2 f[zQr, zhr]^-1)^-1))])), z], _Equal]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 It seems to work but it takes so long for each point, and when it is used in other functions, even longer.

Comment: You could make an interpolation once and use it as an approximation to your function. If you don't have to vary the parameters often, it would be a much faster way to get the work done.

Comment: @MichaelE2 `tp[9.3, 9.30685, -15.50169, 10]` w/ `AccuracyGoal->5` `PrecisionGoal->5` `WorkingPrecision->10` in `NIntegrate` took 500 secs for just one point. What do you think is the better settings in my code? I also removed `MaxRecursion` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to mark out the singularities or eliminate them. We can get rid of one with a substitution `z -> -u^2 + 9`; another one appears only for certain values of `tp`/`tpr`, so we solve for that one. You wouldn't need to solve for it, if `tp` stayed in the approximate range `{tp, -1.1313, 1.1313}`. Omitting `Solve` saves only 5% of the execution time at most, though. Avoiding the singular point, one can save about as much again by using a higher-order integration rule, `Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 11}` (81.7 sec. vs. 88.7 sec. in the OP's `Plot` but over `{tp, -1.1313, 1.1313}`).

```
d = 3;
ag = 16;
pg = 6; (* N.B. *)
wp = 40;
f[z_, zh_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1);

toroottp[tp_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, sig_?NumericQ, 
   zh_?NumericQ] :=
  Module[{tpr, zsr, zQr, sigr, zhr, integrand, singpts},
   {tpr, zsr, zQr, sigr, zhr} = 
    Rationalize[{tp, zs, zQ, sig, zh}, 0];
   
   integrand = ((1/
          z^d) (Sqrt[
           1/(f[z, 
               zhr] (1 + (((f[zsr, zhr]^2 tpr^2)/f[z, zhr]) - 
                   1) (z/
                    zsr)^(2 d) (1/(1 - f[zsr, zhr] tpr^2))))] - (Sqrt[
            zQr^(2 d)/(f[z, 
                zhr] (zQr^(2 d) - 
                 z^(2 d) (1 + sigr^2 f[zQr, zhr]^-1)^-1))])) Dt[z, 
         u] /. z -> -u^2 + 9 // Simplify[#, u > 0] &);
   singpts = 
    Reverse@
     Union@
      Flatten[
       SolveValues[# && Sqrt[9 - zsr] < u < 3, u, Reals] & /@ 
        Cases[FunctionSingularities[integrand, u], _Equal]];
   
   NIntegrate[SetPrecision[integrand, wp],
     (*{z,0,zsr}*){u, 3, Sequence @@ singpts, Sqrt[9 - zsr]},
     AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg,
     WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxRecursion -> 30] - 
    NIntegrate[SetPrecision[
      (1/z^d) (Sqrt[
         zQr^(2 d)/(f[z, 
             zhr] (zQr^(2 d) - 
              z^(2 d) (1 + sigr^2 f[zQr, zhr]^-1)^-1))]), wp], {z, 
      zsr, zQr},
     AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, WorkingPrecision -> wp, 
     MaxRecursion -> 30] - 1/zQr^(d - 1)];

tp[zs_?NumericQ, zQ_?NumericQ, sig_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
 tp /. FindRoot[
   SetPrecision[toroottp[tp, zs, zQ, sig, zh] == 0, wp], {tp, 1, 0.8, 
    1.15}, AccuracyGoal -> ag, PrecisionGoal -> pg, 
   WorkingPrecision -> wp, MaxIterations -> 200];
```